# Changing location of Android Keystore

Tags: android, keystore

I know this is a rather noob question, but surprisingly this hasn't been asked on SO before.

I recently launched my first application on Google Play, and had stored my Android Keystore on a flash drive as advised in [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](https://commonsware.com/Android/). I am the only developer and so don't have problems related to sharing of the keystore with my peers.

But now I want to format the flash drive which, though not necessary, would certainly be better as it has some errors in it. So my question, can I actually back up the .jks file to some other location on my machine and still continue updating my app through it?

Comment: I have heard about backing up the keystore file so in all probability, this will work and I also can just back it up to some place and then update my app through the backed up keystore to check this, but since I didn't find this question on SO, I asked it - for posterity.

Comment: yes. its a standalone file and you can simply use it from any location. Google Play Store now allows storing keys on google infrastructure . follow steps specified in this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Comment: yes, you can backup your.jsk file and user later from any location

Comment: do know about Google App Signing, but didn't apply for it yet. Thanks and can you post it as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

The .jks file can be copied, e-mailed, compressed and uncompressed, et cetera and still be used like the original.